# how to output all images in an entry's loop

Tags: craft3, entry, image, loop

Unfortunately I'm still very new to Craft, but I have a question to which I haven't found an answer here or in the Docs or the ones I found don't seem to work in my case.

I want to output all the images for each entry in this loop and I don't understand how I get the "set image = entry.startbilder" to work that way?

I understand that ".one()" only outputs the first image but how do I change that to output all images? changing that to ".all()" results in an error.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('projekte').all() %}  
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">      
        {% set image = entry.startbilder.one() %}
        {% if image %}
            <img src="{{ image.getUrl('medium') }}" alt="{{ image.title }}" />
        {% endif %}
    </a>        
{% endfor %}
```

thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.all()`, but that will give you an array of [Assets](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-asset.html#public-properties). You can't call `.getUrl()` on an array, so you'd have to loop that array:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('projekte').all() %}  
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">      
        {% set images = entry.startbilder.all() %}

        {% if images |length %}
            {% for image in images %}
                <img src="{{ image.getUrl('medium') }}" alt="{{ image.title }}" />
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </a>        
{% endfor %}
```

If you'd want to [eager load](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/eager-loading-elements.html#eager-loading-image-transform-indexes) the images, this is how you'd do it:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('projekte').with(['startbilder']).all() %}  
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">      
        {% if entry.startbilder |length %}
            {% for image in entry.startbilder %}
                <img src="{{ image.getUrl('medium') }}" alt="{{ image.title }}" />
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </a>        
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hi paul, thank you very much for this detailed answer. if someone has worked with expressionengine for many years before, it is sometimes difficult to adjust to the different approach of craft. I now understand the basic error I've made… and I should always use eager loading because it is much more efficient if I use lots of transformed images, right? thanks!

Comment: It’s always useful, when in devMode, to use {{ dump(variable) }} to see what you’re dealing with. If it’s an array, use a for loop. If it’s an object, look it up in the class reference and see what methods or attributes you can use 